# How to Authenticate LDAP Service with IdentiyServer 4,

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I Am developing an API[Asp.Net Core] + Client [ Angular 6] and I want to authenticate the users with our existing LDAP Service via Identity Server 4. Please help on this implementation.

Comment: This question is a big vague. Are you having a specific technical issue or are you wanting some guidance on how best to approach it? What LDAP service is it?

Comment: @mackie, I want the best approach. LDAP is something like active directory [ need to validate the username with LDAP service ]. If the user exists in that service then I need to grant access to that user.

Comment: If it's Active Directory then I'd seriously consider looking at using ADFS 2016 since it supports OpenID Connect. If not then have a look at the .Net Core compatible LDAP library in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use LDAP (i.e. you don't have access to an OIDC compatible provider like ADFS 2016) then this library should do what you need and is cross platform:

https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard